# Meaning of abbreviation BLH?

Tags: latitude-longitude, history

I cannot find anywhere why `BLH` (where `B` is geographical latitude, `L` geographical longitude and `H` is elliposidal height) is called `BLH`.

The origin of the letter `H` is clear, but what about `B` and `L`?

Many sources over internet, [like this one](https://www.gnu.org/software/gama/manual/html_node/Transformation-from-spatial-to-geographical-coordinates.html), use these same symbols to represent geo points.

Comment: It is required to clarify: BLH (where: B is geodetic latitude, L is geodesic longitude and H is height above the ellipsoid), and geographic latitude is φ, geographic longitude is λ, and for that thanks to the Greeks: -) ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should be abbreviations for the German words `Breite, Länge, Höhe`, which directly translate to `latitude, longitude, height`.

Comment: Thank you!!! Do you know why is German words used? may be you know any reference to any source?

Comment: As far as I know German cartographers were amongst the first to define ellipsoids and conduct extensive land surveys. But I can't give you any sources besides this (only in German available) [Wiki-link](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6niglich-S%C3%A4chsische_Triangulirung). Maybe start your research around the term "triangulation".